# Is the composite of two simple radical extensions another simple radical extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I encountered this (fact? Maybe I misunderstood) in a proof of a lemma in Dummit and Foote where the authors state something which (I think) implies this without proof, namely that the composition of two root extensions is another one. If what they state doesn't require that the composition of two simple radical extensions be another one, please explain why.[image] I tried doing this in various ways, but (as the answer below suggests) this may not even be true. If so, there must be something wrong with my understanding or a way to avoid running into this supposed requirement.

They also didn't prove the statement that the composite of all fields $\sigma{K}$ for $\sigma\in Aut(L/F)$ is precisely $L$ (the Galois closure) and here's my attempt to prove it with $K$ an arbitrary extension of $F$.

Denote the composite of all such fields by $E$ and consider the action of any  $\tau\in Aut(L/F)$ on it. We see that any such $\tau$ sends $E$ into itself (see the edit below). And so, any $\sigma\in Aut(L/F)$ is an automorphism of the field $E$ fixing $F$, But the number of embeddings $N$ of $E$ into an algebraic closure which contains $L$ that fix $F$ is the order of the set of cosets $\left|Aut\left(L/F\right)\right|/\left|Aut\left(L/E\right)\right|$ by the fundamental theorem.
Combining these results we get, $$\frac{\left|Aut\left(L/F\right)\right|}{\left|Aut\left(L/E\right)\right|}\ge\left|Aut\left(E/F\right)\right|\ge\left|Aut\left(L/F\right)\right|$$ which (since $L/E$ is galois) leads to $$\left|Aut\left(L/E\right)\right|=\left[L:E\right]=1$$

Is this correct?

Edit: Let $B_i=\left\{b_{i,1},b_{i,2},...b_{i,m}\right\}$ denote any set of elements that span $\sigma_iK$ over $F$. Define $P=\left\{p_1,p_2,...p_s\right\}$ to be the set of all possible products of elements $b_{i,r}$ in the union $B_1 \cup B_2 \cup ...B_q$. The set $P$ spans $E$ over $F$. So, for arbitrary $\alpha \in E$ we have $$\alpha=\sum_{j=0}^sa_jp_j                          $$ $a_j \in F$ applying some $\tau \in Aut(L/F)$ and noting that $\tau$ fixes the $a_j$'s, we get $$\tau\left(\alpha\right)=\sum_{j=0}^sa_j\tau\left(p_j\right)$$

Each $p_j$ is a product of $b$'s in the union above and each $b_{i,r}$ is in some $\sigma_{i}K$ so $\tau$ sends it to an element of $\tau\sigma_{i}K$ which is an element of $E$ by definition. So, the image of a product of any number of $b$'s will still be in $E$ since all the images are in $E$. So, the image of $p_j$ is some $\beta$ again in $E$ which may or may not be in $P$, but this doesn't matter since $\tau\left(\alpha\right)$ is in $E$ anyway and we started with an arbitrary $\alpha$. Noting that $\tau$ can't send two elements to the same element since it's an automorphism of the larger field $L$, I conclude that any such $\tau$ is an automorphism of $E$ fixing $F$.

Comment: "We see that any such $\tau$ sends $E$ into itself since its action would be on elements that are in the fields $\sigma{K}$ for $\sigma\in Aut(L/F)$" -- No. The field $E$ is a composite of fields $\sigma{K}$ for $\sigma\in Aut(L/F)$, but it does not mean that every element of $E$ is of the form $\sigma{k}$ for some $\sigma\in Aut(L/F)$ and $k \in K$.

Comment: Yes you're right. See the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think they ever state that composition of simple radical extension is also a radical extension. Moreover, I simply do not think it's true. For example, I don't think that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is a simple radical extension: its Galois group is not cyclic.

The only thing that they claim is that the composition of root extensions is also a root extensions, and that's easy. Suppose we have two root extensions: $F = F_0 \subset F_1 \subset \ldots \subset F_p$, and $F = G_0 \subset G_1 \subset \ldots \subset G_q$, such that $F_{i+1} = F_i(\sqrt[n_i]{a_i})$ for some $a_i \in F_i$, and same for $G_i$. WLOG we can assume that $p = q$.

Then, the composition of $F_p$ and $G_p$ is also a root extension: since $G_1 = G_0(\sqrt[k_0]{b_0})$, $b_0 \in G_0 = F = F_0$. Thus, we set $H_1 = F_1(\sqrt[k_0]{b_0}) = F_0(\sqrt[n_0]{a_0})(\sqrt[k_0]{b_0})$, and we see that $H_1$ is a root extension, and $F_1 \subset H_1$, $G_1 \subset H_1$ -- in fact, $H_1$ is the composition of $F_1$ and $G_1$. Similarly, since $a_1, b_1 \in H_1$, we set $H_2 = H_1(\sqrt[n_1]{a_1})(\sqrt[k_1]{b_1})$, and again $H_2$ is a root extension, and the composition of $F_2$ and $G_2$. Continuing this way, we obtain that $H_p$ is a root extension and the composition of $F_p$ and $G_p$.

Comment: The definition of a root extension in the book states that it must be the end of an ascending chain of simple radical extensions. Plus they state in the parentheses " such that each individual extension in the process is a simple radical extension." the process they refer to is at some point the composition of simple radical extensions. I'm confused.

Comment: If $F \subset G$ is a root extension, that is, a composition of simple radical extensions $F \subset F_1 \subset \ldots \subset F_n = G$, and if $G \subset H$ is also a composition of simple root extensions $G \subset G_1 \subset \ldots \subset G_k = H$, then obviously $F \subset H$ is also a composition of simple root extensions $F \subset F_1 \subset \ldots \subset F_n \subset G_1 \subset \ldots \subset G_k = H$

Comment: This isn't what is meant by the question. Here's what I mean, let $K_1$ and $K_2$  be two simple radical extensions of the same base field $F$. Is their composite ( the smallest extension of $F$ which contains them both) another simple radical extension? I don't think the authors mean what you mention in the comment. Just check the proof of the lemma, I don't think what you say fits.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right, I sloppily misread it.

That said, 1) As the example in my reply shows, composite of two simple radical extension is *not* a simple radical extension. 2) Clearly the composite of two *root* extensions *is* also a root extensions (as a (finite) root extension is of the form $F \subset F(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, where $a_i$ satisfy $(a_i)^n - a = 0$ for some $a \in F$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so if you composite it with another root extension $F \subset F(b_1, \ldots, b_k)$, their composite is $F \subset F(a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_k)$, a root extension).

Comment: Let $F_0$ be the base field and let $F_i =F_{i-1}\left(\sqrt[n_i]{a_{i-1}}\right)$ where $a_{i-1} \in F_{i-1}$ $i=1, 2 , 3...$. A root extension is the end of an ascending chain of extensions of the form: $$ F_0 \subset F_1 \subset F_2....\subset F_s$$ This is the definition in the book. I don't think this agrees with your definition since you say that every $a_i$ is in the base field whereas the other definition says it's in the directly preceding field. How is the composition of two root extension in this definition another one if  the intermediate fields aren't simple radical extensions?

Comment: I know your answer is what the original question asks for but I don't want to accept it just yet because that would discourage people from checking the question out and possibly adding something extra. Forgive me :). Is the proof attempt in the second part of the question correct?

Comment: Ah, I think you're right again. Let me amend my answer, as I don't think I'm going to fit in the comment :) It's all intuitively obvious to me, and it's the same idea anyway, which is what makes my thinking lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can take it as comment, you need to define the possible cases because the terms you are using are not standard

- Simple root extension $F(a^{1/n})/F$ with minimal polynomial $x^n-a$. In general a tower or compositum of such won't a simple root extension.
- Cyclotomic extension $F(\zeta_k)/F$
- A tower $F_l/F_0$ of such extensions : what we usually call a radical extension. Any element of a radical extension has an expression in term of nested sum/product/quotient of $n$-th roots of elements of $F$ and roots of unities.
- The normal closure of $F_l/F_0$ is obtained by adding to $F_l$ the roots of unities needed to make $x^{n_j}-a_j$ split completely as well as a root of $x^{n_j}-\sigma(a_j)$ for all $F$-homomorphism $\sigma : F_l \to \overline{F_l}$. By induction $\sigma(a)$ is in a radical extension so the normal closure is a radical extension. If I say normal instead of Galois it is because $\Bbb{F}_p(t)/\Bbb{F}_p(t^p)$ is a normal non-Galois radical extension.
- Cyclic extensions are radical extensions (add $\zeta_k$ to the base field so that $E(\zeta_k)/F(\zeta_k)$ is again cyclic, with the primitive element theorem $E(\zeta_k)=F(\zeta_k)(\beta)$, then $\gamma=\sum_{r=1}^m \sigma^r(\beta)\zeta_k^r$ satisfies $\sigma(\gamma) = \zeta_k^{-1}\gamma$ so it is a $m=[E(\zeta_k):F(\zeta_k)]$-th root)
- A tower of radical extensions such that $F_l/F_0$ is Galois (It is easy to show by induction adding iteratively the roots of $x^n-a$ to the base field that it decomposes as a tower of cyclic Galois radical extensions, this implies the whole Galois group is solvable (since $Gal(F_j/F_0) = Gal(F_l/F_0)/Gal(F_l/F_j)$) conversely any Galois extension with solvable Galois group decomposes as a tower of cyclic extensions, so we have the main theorem : radical extension = contained in a normal extension with solvable Galois group)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am familiar with most of what you wrote in the answer as these things are mentioned in previous pages in the book and, in fact, once I take the phrase "..such that each individual extension in the process is a simple radical extension." in the proof of the lemma for granted, everything becomes understandable but I can't justify that statement. Is the proof attempt in the second part of the question correct?